# Numpy python - calculating sum of columns from irregular dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array for scores, and for which, I need to get sum of each columns at 3rd level in Python. I am using **Numpy** to achieve this.

```
import numpy as np
```

Data is something like:

```
score_list = [
    [[1,1,3], [1,2,5]],
    [[2,7,5], [4,1,3]]
]
```

This should return:

> [[3 8 8] [5 3 8]]

Which is happening correctly using this:

```
sum_array = np_array.sum(axis=0)
print(sum_array)
```

However, if I have irregular shape like this:

```
score_list = [
    [[1,1], [1,2,5]],
    [[2,7], [4,1,3]]
]
```

I expect it to return:

> [[3 8] [5 3 8]]

However, it comes up with warning and the return value is:

> [list([1, 1, 2, 7]) list([1, 2, 5, 4, 1, 3])]

How can I get expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

numpy will try to cast it into an nd array which will fail, instead consider passing each sublist individually using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```py
score_list = [
    [[1,1], [1,2,5]],
    [[2,7], [4,1,3]]
]

import numpy as np
res = [np.sum(x,axis=0) for x in zip(*score_list)]
print(res)
```

```
[array([3, 8]), array([5, 3, 8])]
```

Comment: This solution uses numpy, and works even after changing shape/dimension

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution for doing this, keep in mind that it doesn't use numpy and will be very inefficient for larger matrices (but for smaller matrices runs just fine).

```
# Create matrix
score_list = [
[[1,1,3], [1,2,5]],
[[2,7,5], [4,1,3]]
]

# Get each row
for i in range(1, len(score_list)):

  # Get each list within the row
  for j in range(len(score_list[i])):

    # Get each value in each list
    for k in range(len(score_list[i][j])):

        # Add current value to the same index 
        # on the first row 
        score_list[0][j][k] += score_list[i][j][k]

print(score_list[0])
```

There is bound to be a better solution but this is a temporary fix for you :)

Edit. Made more efficient

Comment: i think creating i,j,k and the if condition are going to take like 95% of this function's runtime, you could get away without creating them by using generators or builtin functions like `sum` and `chain` also note that you don't need to do the if check in the innermost loop if `i` is being created in the outermost loop, it's doing much more checks than it actually needs to do, also you could start i from 1 instead of 0 by `range(1,len(score_list))` therefore removing the if condition entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Implementing just the last bit of advice you gave cuts down the total time the code takes to run by 30%. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
a = np.vstack([np.array(score_list[x], dtype='object')
              for x in range(len(score_list))])
[np.add(*[x for x in a[:, i]]) for i in range(a.shape[1])]
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
a = sum(score_list, [])
b = [a[x] for x in range(0,len(a),2)]
c = [a[x] for x in range(1,len(a),2)]
[np.add(x[0], x[1]) for x in [b, c]]
```

---

Output:

```
[array([3, 8]), array([5, 3, 8])]
```